# Do the cold welds that cause static friction also affect the lifting force?

Tags: newtonian-mechanics, friction

In my physics book static friction is explained by cold welds between contact points.

If I now try to lift this object is there an initial max static lifting force which is slightly greater than the weight of the object?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Lifting frictional force and relative values for kinetic vs static friction](https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/128442/)

Comment: Note that real tribology is a bit more complicated than intro physics books suggest...